Windows 24H2 issues with commands performed in Command Prompt with elevated privileges
I have recently updated to Windows 11 24H2 from 23H2. (This also happens on a clean install of 24H2 with the device formatted).
I have to perform certain tasks in a Command Prompt with elevated privileges, especially after the install of new Nvidia Drivers, where I have to delete certain files in C:\Windows\System32\lxss\lib, and then create symlinks in that folder - This is for use in WSL.
The problem I have is that 24H2 does not allow me to perform the actions of deleting and symlinking. (As stated this is in Command Prompt with elevated privileges).
In Windows 11 23H2 this is possible.
After I rolled back from Windows 11 24H2 to 23H2, it worked again. I thought doing a clean install of Windows 11 24H2 might resolve the issue, but it did not.
I have tried using a standard sudo, (no changes to settings), but that also did not work.
The error that I get in all the scenarios is "Access Denied.
Any help would be appreciated

Please add the actual commands you're trying to your question (This? https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5548#issuecomment-1982306717). You can't delete files that: are open/in-use (close the locking process), marked as read-only, or don't have a permissions entry for Administrators (may require taking ownership). That's usually it besides some edge cases like antivirus or corruption
